# モバイル版での閲覧時、回答の段落がわずかにスクロールする

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン, モバイル

スマホからのアクセス時、質問ページで各回答部分の段落がなぜか上下に数ピクセル分だけスライドする状態になっており、ページのスクロールをするつもりでスワイプしてもうまく動作しない場合があります。

**画面の同じ位置、同じサイズで切り出した画像:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力] [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**確認環境:**

Android 版 Chrome 87.0.4280.101

Comment: 関連投稿: [Answers in mobile site scroll slightly - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356917/)

Comment: Google Chrome であれば Android に限らず、 PC の Chrome でも問題の動作が確認できました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

同様のバグに言及している [Stack Exchange の質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356917)が status-complete になりました。そこで再度スタック・オーバーフローでの再現確認を行ったところ再現が出来なかったため、このバグは既にすべてのサイトで修正済みのようです。

---

参考:

1. [Answers in mobile site scroll slightly - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356917)